# Eclipse Windows Builder dynamically change content of panel

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using WindowsBuilder (Eclipse) to generate a simple GUI. Basically, I have a series of buttons ("Add Book", "Add DVD", "Add Magazine", etc..) add the top of the gui, and a JPanel underneath them. I would need to display a different series of elements (textfields, radio buttons etc) depending on which button the user presses. I have understood the basics of adding elements, but how can I define these multiple panel structures?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would need to display a different series of elements (textfields, radio buttons etc) depending on which button the user presses.

You should be using a CardLayout which will allow you to swap panels depending on the button pressed. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) work a working example.